# An object is in the rendered image and I cant find it to remove it

Tags: rendering

So I made an apartment(not finished) and I wanted to see how it looked and for a while now I saw that only when I render an image I see a floating object.
Anyone knows how to delete this object?

This is how it looks if I enter Rendered mode:

[image]

And this is where, after rendering, it's abvious that I have an object floating there....

[image]

Comment: Maybe that object is hidden (H). Press Alt+H to unhide it, then you can select it and delete it.

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stacke Exchange! In addition to what's mentioned above, You can also scroll through the Outliner to see if there are any objects that have the little eye icon greyed out. If they do, that means they'll show up in the final render, but not in the viewport.